# Two groups with the same name in the php regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an input which contains substring in the format of `TXT number` or `number TXT`. I would like to write regexp which will match the format and returns only the number.

I came up with something like this:

`$regex = '/TXT(?<number>[0-9]+)|(?<number>[0-9]+)TXT/'`

The problem is that the compiler says that group with name `number` is already defined even though there is or operator in between.

Is it possible in php to write 2 groups with the same name? If it is not then how can I write regexp like that?

Comment: Use `(?J)` flag: `'/(?J)TXT(?<number>[0-9]+)|(?<number>[0-9]+)TXT/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write 2 groups with the same name you need to use the `(?J)` inline flag:

```
'/(?J)TXT(?<number>[0-9]+)|(?<number>[0-9]+)TXT/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/htvF79/1)

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> `J (PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED)`
>   The `(?J)` internal option setting changes the local `PCRE_DUPNAMES` option. Allow duplicate names for subpatterns. As of PHP 7.2.0 *J* is supported as modifier as well.

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/4MHGa):

```
$regex = '/(?J)TXT(?<number>[0-9]+)|(?<number>[0-9]+)TXT/';
if (preg_match_all($regex, "TXT123 and 456TXT1", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        echo $m["number"] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Note that in your case, you do not need the groups:

```
'/TXT\K[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=TXT)/'
```

The lookarounds will also do the job here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|` and add a space between the digits and the TXT.

```
(?|TXT (?<number>[[0-9]+)|(?<number>[[0-9]+) TXT)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXik6V/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Hh3s0)

For example

```
$re = '/(?|TXT (?<number>[[0-9]+)|(?<number>[[0-9]+) TXT)/';
$str = 'TXT 4
4 TXT';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["number"]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 4
)
```